serving a m3u8 file via nginx for stream
Edit: I've stripped it right back to just havinga couple files and the manifest in the public directory of the project, elminating ngnix configuration. It must now be down to the generation of the file being wrong somehow.
In the meantime instead of playing from a manifest via a file list and http/2 to stream through. But that may not be ideal as theres 28 days worth of footage in 30 second chunks to consider.
Trying to get chunked streaming working. But not sure how to complete the final steps.
heres the project gist:
1 - upload 30 second chunks to cloudflare (works fine)
2 - when requesting a stream from the webapp ask a node+ngnix instance to generate the manifest (works fine)
3 - serve the generated manifest via a nginx location and start the stream
(does not work so fine).
noting the web app and the nginx are running locally:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/request-manifest?manifest_id=123
other details:
the files are mkv format,
the mkv files are playable with standard html5 video when requesting the file directly
the manifest doesn't play when the url is loaded into vlc
a chunk file could be missing and the frotnend would need to mitigate that (skip to next chunk or serve up a missing footage frame of some kind)
since VLC cant play it either I might guess the problem is with nginx or the manifest itself here is the config
The manifest text content is returned when making the request

worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    # Logging
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        listen       80;
        # listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        # SSL configuration
        # ssl_certificate     /path/to/your/fullchain.pem;
        # ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/privkey.pem;
        # ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        # ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            return 403;
        }

        location /generate-manifest {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
            
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                return 204;
            }

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Query-String $query_string;
        }

        location /request-manifest {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
            
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                return 204;
            }


            set $manifest_id $arg_manifest_id;

            alias /var/nginx/manifests/;
            
            try_files $manifest_id.m3u8 =404;
        }
    }
}


Just a simple test with the html5 video player

<video 
  id="player" 
  width="640" 
  height="268" 
>
  <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/request-manifest?manifest_id=123" type='application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'>
</video>


example manifest

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0

#EXTINF:30,
https://[secret].cloudflarestorage.com/video-streams/7ea3cbef-4da0-11ed-bdcc-baf70a43c072/1728953187133.mkv
#EXTINF:30,
https://[secret].cloudflarestorage.com/video-streams/7ea3cbef-4da0-11ed-bdcc-baf70a43c072/1728953217133.mkv
#EXTINF:1,
https:/[secret].cloudflarestorage.com/video-streams/MISSING_FOOTAGE.mkv
#EXT-X-ENDLIST


have also tried with standard examples from hls.js and video.js but I don't think the problem is on the frontend as I'd expect it to play with vlc.
Definately missing a key peice of knowledge here, just not sure what to try out or read up on next
Any ideas out there? Thank you.
